# VisualBrush in Polygon WPF

Tags: wpf

I have this control:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="Gray" BorderThickness="3" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        <Polygon Points="0,0 100,10 100,90 0,100" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Polygon.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MainBorder}"/>
            </Polygon.Fill>
        </Polygon>
    </StackPanel>
```

The Polygon is not a square but I am trying to make the border be drawn on the edge of the Polygon, meaning that the top right pixel will be at the top right point of the polygon (100,10), same with the bottom right (100,90) and it won't cut the image.

In my case there is no border but a full grid with content, the Border is just for the example.

Is there any way to do this?